# Stringstream compile error occurs only in linux environment

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I wrote a program in C++ using Visual Studio on my desktop.  In that environment, the program compiles and executes without error, and the output is exactly as expected.

However, when I try to move my source code to a linux system and compile it, the I encounter errors related to my use of stringstream.  The code has the form:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    stringstream ssline;
    ssline = stringstream(line); //where the error occurs
}
```

I use this assignment operation many times throughout my program, and like I said - I didn't cause any problems when I used Visual Studio to compile.  On my linux system, both the gnu compiler and the intel compiler throw the same error, which reads:

```
ProgramName.cpp:73:12: error: use of deleted function
‘std::basic_stringstream<char>& std::basic_stringstream<char>::operator=
(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’
    ssline = stringstream(line);
                ^
In file included from ProgramName.cpp:13:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/sstream:502:11: note:
‘std::basic_stringstream<char>& std::basic_stringstream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_stringstream<char>&)’
is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
    class basic_stringstream : public basic_iostream<_CharT, _Traits>
```

I do not know what to make of this error, nor why it seems to be system dependent.  I can rewrite my source code to avoid the use of stringstream, but I would prefer not to.  Because again, I know it works on my desktop environment.

I appreciate any help that can be offered in resolving this difficulty.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It seems](https://godbolt.org/g/tPSuFM) that GCC has move assignment for `std::stringstream` since GCC 5, and you use GCC 4.8.2.

Your GCC is too old, you need to upgrade.

Comment: Always amazes me that people are using compiler versions four major releases (or more) behind the current version.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, who knows that their constraints are. We have been stuck with VS 2008 at my work for a while :)

Comment: @ RSahu  These constraints are in my experience somewhat artificial and a result of bad practice, piling up technical debt. There was a post the other day from some guy "upgrading" from GCC 3.x to GCC 4.x. Personally, I like to be one or maybe two versions behind the latest, but not four or five.

Comment: It sucks and I agree with you, Neil, it just leads to future problems. But... It can take a fair amount of political capital to force a compiler upgrade and all of the testing that goes with it. I have to suffer with BCC32 5, GCCs 3.3; 4.6; 4.9,  and Visual Studios 2008 and 2010 on a regular basis because the organization I work for thinks this costs them less money.

Comment: @Neil - Often times we don't have a choice in the compiler provided by the platform. The reality of the situation is, GCC 4.8 and GCC 4.9 are still frequently encountered in the field. Most ARM dev-boards come with GCC 4.8 or 4.9. Half the machines on the GCC compile farm are GCC 4.8 or 4.9.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ssline.str(line);` instead will accomplish what you want (including the continued use of `std::stringstream`).

TL;DR Your code is not compiling because `stringstream` instances are not copyable (in your GCC compiler, refs @HolyBlackCat's answer).

Take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment. There is a section titled "Deleted implicitly-declared copy assignment operator". What's happening here in your code is that since `std::stringstream` does not have an assignment operator and you're trying to use it the compiler tries to generate one. However, because `std::stringstream` instances are not copyable the implicitly-declared operator is defined as deleted.